# Не могу подключить библиотеку java.time.LocalDate

Tags: android-studio, импорт

В Андроид Студио не могу подключить библиотеку java.time.LocalDate. Выделяет красным LocalDate. Стоит java 8.
Думаю студио пытается искать из android sdk, а не из java sdk.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Еклипсе все нормально.

Answer (score -1):

Вытащил из jre rt.jar и добавил в андроид студио как внешнюю библиотеку.